# App Store login popup. Input doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, simulator, storekit

I'm writing an app in which I can buy some stuff per InAppPurchases. The requests work fine, I am getting the right infos from Apple Stores but when it comes to buying an error occurs. When I send a request with a payment to do I am getting a popup window from Apple with a request to Sign in. I click 'Use Existing Apple ID' and another popup shows up where I can actually put my AppleID.

The problem is I cannot write anything into those TextFields (neither username nor password). The focus works fine, I can click both of them and they have the cursor blinking.

I have also two TextFields on my ViewController and they are not disabled even when Apple Popup is visible and the rest is darkened.

I'm working on iOS Simulator with iOS 8.0 on it and with XCode 6 - beta5.

How can I solve this issue? Maybe a delegate would be helpful, but I can get no ID or something for Apple-generated-windows.

Comment: Use your simulator keyboard instead of your PC's keyboard

Comment: It doesn't work neither. The simulator keyboard is showing beneath the background of the popup and I can't click anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have this problem if you are attaching a real device, but don't forget first to sign out from Appstore  on your test device.